# How to create an operating system on top of Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: macos, ubuntu, unix, operating-systems, c

I want create an operating system the way Mac did, building a program on top of a Unix operating system. I am planning to make  a small operating system with a small amount of functions using C. I do not need coding help, but I need a way to boot my program without needing to have Ubuntu load. Is there any way to do that? I don't want to edit any Unix material, so if I want to I could use a little out of it.

Comment: I don't think that what you are asking is really what you want.  The Linux operating system that Ubuntu is built on provides the interface with the hardware as well as the basic C runtime so that your programs can run and generate output (as well as many other basic functions).  Are you sure you want to re-write all of that (drivers, support libraries, etc.)?  I think you need to get a better understanding of what you want and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @user2649805 - You do understand that Ubuntu uses Linux kernel and OS X is based on 3 decades of work on a Unix kernel right? OS X is actually based on a fork from `FreeBSD` and `NetBSD`. Ubuntu is running on the Linux kernel and launches for instance a window mangement shell which handles the all of the desktop behavior. **OS X wasn't built on top of anything its actually a Unix kernel.** Download and compile Darwin to get started.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)

Comment: `I need a way to boot my program without needing to have Ubuntu load` -  So use a bootloader.  Grub is the standard on Linux systems these days.  Just configure Grub to load your kernel.

Comment: So i need to build a kernel... how does osx 10 look so different than Darwin? Do they make new graphics and just call everything in from darwin?

Comment: @user2649805 You're confusing the video server with the kernel. It looks different because they made their own window manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any good bootloader for your OS. My favorite one in grub. First create a kernel image then learn coding in grub. Finally, you will be able to achieve your goal